# Correct definition of differentiability for several variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I came across two different definition of differentiability of a function of several variable at a point.

1) (due to Spivak) $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a$ if for some linear function $\lambda:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ we have $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)|}{|h|}=0$

2) (found [here](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111104092/5)) $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a$ if for some linear function $\lambda:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ we have $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)}{|h|}=0\in\mathbb R^n$

Are these two definitions equivalent? I can see 2 implies 1, but what about the reverse inclusion?

In case they are not equivalent which one should be taken as correct?

Comment: You basically ask if $\lim |a_n|=0$ $\iff$ $\lim a_n=0$. Note that $-|a_n|\le a_n\le |a_n|$

Comment: So they are equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, use the squeeze theorem for limits.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: They are equivalent but the inequalities $-|a_n| \leq a_n \leq |a_n|$ are not valid here since we are dealing with convergence of vectors in $\mathbb R^{m}$, not real numbers.

Comment: The second definition is a not meaningful, strictly speaking, as the left hand side is the limit of a vector from $\mathbb R^m$, while the right hand side seems just to be the zero from $\mathbb R$. If it is suppsed to be the zero element of $\mathbb R^m$, then it makes sense again and the definition of what it means to converge in $\mathbb R^m$ then yields the first definition.